Как верно указать автора публикациий, его id, title и описание в файле mpd
При кодировании видео, при помощи FFMPEG. На выходе получила файл mpd, в нем только аудио и видеодорожка. Так же присутствуют еще два тега.
<ProgramInformation>
</ProgramInformation>
<ServiceDescription id="0">
</ServiceDescription>

Не понимаю, что в них должно быть и нужны ли они. В интернете прочитала что в атрибуте
<ProgramInformation>
  <title>Наименование публикации</title>
</ProgramInformation>

Не знаю верно, я также рассчитываю добавить в файл наименование публикации и короткое описание. А так же имя автора и его id...
Кто подскажет, как верно вписать все эти параметры, дабы в дальнейшем была возможность вытащить их в javascript.
Возможно у кого есть ссылка на толковую документацию, где можно почитать про это. Спс...
